# Hot reload with typescript and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm facing problems while developing both frontend (Redux) and backend (Express) in Typescript. I could not make hot reload work. Here is configuration of `webpack.config.js` in root folder:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

const config = {
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        'user': ['./dist/client/User/index', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client'],
        'guest': ['./dist/client/Guest/index', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CheckerPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/static'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                options: { cacheDirectory: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    node: { fs: 'empty' }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

In `src` I separate two folders `client` and `server`, my `npm start` script is `tsc && node dist/server`. In `server/index` I declare utilization of webpack compiler like this:

```
import config from '../../webpack.config';
const compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
```

When I start the application, webpack builds normally, but it never build hot reload when I make changes in client files. I spent a whole day but still confused and don't know how to fix it yet.

Answer (score -1):

are you currently using react 17?

if so, create the following in the .env file

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3jJv.png)

Comment: React 13 ?? This is just practically impossible to using so outdated version of react by user who use typescript and own webpack configs.

Comment: What does this solution do?